# How can I convert the first letter of each sentence to uppercase and all other letters to lowercase?

Tags: java, string

Part of grammar checking in my project.
I have a paragraph and I want to change all the first letters of each sentence to be in upper case.
All other letters in the sentence must be lowercase.

```
"lijo was very intelligent.but his Character was not Good.He Played FootBall .
he is veryClever,and wise."

output

"Lijo was very intelligent.But his character was not good.He played football .
He is veryclever,and wise."
```

I have done the above like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String org= "lijo was very 'intelligent . but his Character was not Good.He Played    FootBall .he is veryClever,and wise.";
    String [] temp=org.split("\\.");
    int len=temp.length;
    String ne = ".";
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        temp[i]=temp[i].toUpperCase();
        temp[i]=(temp[i].substring(0, 1)).toUpperCase()+(temp[i].substring(1, temp[i].length())).toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(temp[i]); 
    }
}
```

**Is there any easier way to do this?**

Comment: Does the above code work?

Comment: yes it gives output but i am looking for a simple idea.

Comment: Of course, you do not solve the problem of proper names, which should have leading caps, or the problem of acronyms, which should be all caps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
private static final Pattern SENTENCE_START = Pattern.compile("(?:^|[.]\\s*)([a-z])");
private String sentenceCase(String org) {
    char[] chars = org.toCharArray();
    Matcher m = SENTENCE_START.matcher(org);
    while (m.find()) {
        chars[m.start(1)] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[m.start(1)]);
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Regex explanation:

```
(?:^|[.]\s*)([a-z])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`(?: )` - unnamed group
`^` - start of string
`|` - or
`[.]` - `.` character
`\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
`[a-z]` - lowercase char

Answer (score 1):

There is **NO** way to do this both easily and properly. Determining where a sentence starts or ends is very tricky and has a lot of subtle problems. For instance, not all periods end sentences; some could be used in abbreviations or numbers. A somewhat sophisticated language model would be required for reasonable guesses in those cases.

Furthermore, it's not always certain that a sentence should start with a capital. For instance, I seem to recall that sentences starting with a last name along the lines of "von xxx" shouldn't be capitalized, etc.

tl;dr: You can do it the easy way and have it make lots of mistakes, or you can do it the really hard way and have it work in most but probably not all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Most people will tell you to split on a period, chopping your text up into sentences.  It will work for the right input, but your first "Mr.", "PhD." or "et. al." will cause the whole thing to fail horribly.

Since you mentioned grammar, you need to become accquainted with computer grammars.  Look into BNF and create a few context-sensitive attempts to model English language.  Then, when you have a good idea of tokens vs productions, start with a simple dictionary that labels each bit of text with it's possible parts of speech (ex. "root" can be a noun and a verb, depending).

If you are well versed in programming, then I have had some decent success with "compiler-compilers" like JavaCC; however, there is a learning curve.  You might want to give a hand using something like JParsec if you want to go the parser-combinator route, which seems to be the current "new thing" on the block.

With those elements, you will start to get results; but, don't expect your results to be that great.  This is a big project that others have made their careers on.  However, at least you will get the right results (and learn a lot in the process).  Always favor right over convenient; because, code has a tendency to outlive it's easy requirements, and adding in correctness is a very hard task indeed.

Comment: @404 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form https://javacc.java.net/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree http://nltk.org/book/ch08.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree and so on.  It's really quite a list, and to make it really work for everything, it is cutting edge research which is worthy of grant funding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String[] parts = input.split("\\.");
for(String part : parts){
   resultBuilder.append(part.substring(0,1).toUppercase())
                .append(part.substring(1).toLowercase())
                .append(".");
}
return resultBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: `\i` is not a valid regex in java

Comment: Also, if `part` is empty (for `input="..x"`) then `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` gets thrown.

Comment: Also input `. but` is not converted to `. But`

Comment: I know. This was just something I quickly whipped together to solve his simpler case. To have a full solution that works in every case you'd need quite a bit more (complicated) code